# link aggregation between switch and router

Tags: cisco, switch, router

Here i have this topology in my company 
[image]

cores configure with ***VSS***, As we can see single link connecting each router to each core which make this link single point of fail, so I need to add link between each router and the other core acting as something like ether channel between two switches to avoid this failure probability from my network , like the next topology
[image]

i'm asking about if there is any link aggregation method on the router side (some thing like L3 port aggregation on switches )

***NOTE*** my routers plateform is 2921 and run Version 15.2(4)M6a

Comment: It depends on the router. Port channeling is normally a layer-2 (switch) STP thing Most routers can't port channel. I know some more recent Cisco routers with newer IOS can channel ports.

Comment: Cross-Stack EtherChannel configuration example http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/switches/catalyst-3750-series-switches/69979-cross-stack-etherchannel.html Is this what you mean ?

Comment: dear i'm not asking about etherchannel configurations from the **Switch side** i just ask about how you doing link aggregation from the **router side**

Comment: You could improve your question by editing it to add more details. You may find our [Question Checklist](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/292/33) helpful when editing your question. For example: the vendor/model of the devices and software versions. Some devices support a form of L3 LAG, but many do not. I am also not sure if you can do a L3 LAG in a VSS environment (never looked into it). Also, would solutions based on HSRP/VRRP/GLBP be acceptable?

Comment: @ YLearn so may you mean router could support L3 LAG, it just depend on the platform or software of this router ?

Comment: Based on your edit, the answer is still dependent on if the hardware/software supports LAG. Also, are you concerned about the redundancy aspect of LAG, the increased bandwidth capacity, or both?

Comment: @YLearn no just redundancy so L3 LAG is must

Comment: @YLearn what if my plateform not support L3 LAG ?

Comment: You can get redundancy without LAG. Use HSRP, VRRP or GLBP.

Comment: Are your core switches layer-3 capable? If so, just link to the routers with layer-3 links. The routing protocol will failover automatically.

Comment: @YLearn i already run VSS between the two core switches which make them acting as a one switch , my question is how to connect two cables from those two switches (one per each) to each router . how HSRP ,VRRP or GLBP could help

Comment: @ Ron Maupin my core swich support L3 and i route all the down stream networks to the wan router through it , may you explain how the routing could be if i connect two cables to the wan router for example with out L3 link aggregation .

Comment: A layer-3 link between the switch and the router is usually a /30 or /31. It's best to define the layer-3 address directly on the port instead of an SVI. For Cisco switches, put "no switchport" on the interface, and configure the interface as you would on a router. Run a routing protocol between all the layer-3 devices, and, with redundant links, any one link down will be routed around.

Comment: @ Ron Maupin so you mean run something like RIP V2 between routers and switch . sure it would help  , but i wonder Cisco have no other choice  for L3 aggregation between router and switch.

Comment: You said are only looking for redundancy instead of bandwidth aggregation. That's what routing protocols are for; if properly configured they route around broken links. You could just run OSPF on your layer-3 devices, and each would have a complete understanding of all the paths available to get from one place in the network to any other. This is a conventional way to connect a layer-3 core switch pair to upstream routers. Some Cisco router/IOS combinations have something like what you are requesting, but, often, the simple method is best and can be used with almost any router.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments, you can achieve link redundancy by installing a link from each physical core switch chassis to each router.  Each link would be a point-to-point (usually /30 or /31) routed link.  The core and the routers would need to run an IGP routing protocol.  Your devices support OSPF, and it is easy to set up and include every layer-3 interface.  When a link is disabled, OSPF will route around the broken link.

This is a simple, conventional network topology that is easy to support on most business-class networks, and it seems to provide what you are looking for.

Comment: i beleve it could solve the issue and in this case may i use loopback interface in VG to register it on the CUCM

Comment: Using loopbacks is the preferred method for address references that you want to be reachable via routing when an interface or link goes down.

Comment: so what about IRP , i posted answer based on this feature

Comment: IRB is not widely used. Layer-3 convergence on a change to the network is an order of magnitude faster than layer-2 convergence. Your problem is a straightforward one which can be dealt with using a standard network topology and practices. I'm not sure why you would want to deviate from that. Your problem was solved a long time ago, and the solution is easy and proven.

Answer (score 2):

here i found very good solution for this case is to use ***IRB (Integrated Routing and Bridging)*** , refer to this very long discussion [IRB why and how?](https://serverfault.com/questions/254347/what-is-a-cisco-bvi-interface-what-is-it-used-for)

A BVI (Bridge Group Virtual Interface) is a routed interface that represents a set of interfaces that gets bridged. so we need to configure IRB from the router side and the core side and it will provide the redundancy needed

i found some examples for such configuration in the next link [EXAMPLE](http://blog.xuite.net/flytw1/ccie/98038572-Cisco+Bridge-Group+Virtual+Interface(BVI)+Configuration+for+High+Availability)
and i try it on GNS3 and it is working properly

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if link aggregation is possible on a router, but if all you need is redundancy, link aggregation is NOT the way to go. Link aggregation is for increasing the bandwidth of a logical connection, not for redundancy.

Comment: for the 1st part of your answer , link aggregation is possible on ISR routers refer to the next link [link aggregation](https://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/products/collateral/routers/3800-series-integrated-services-routers-isr/prod_white_paper0900aecd806f698a.pdf) , for the second part of your answer i agree with you main target behind LAG is to increase the BW , but it can provide you redundancy as well in case of one cable down the other is up